# Preencher campo CAPTCHA via CURL PHP com "Submit em Javascript"

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, libcurl, captcha

Como faço para preencher um campo de uma página em cURL sendo que esta não envia os dados via formulário, e sim via Javascript?

A página em questão é essa:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/juridico.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='dwr/engine.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='dwr/util.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='dwr/interface/ValidacaoCaptchaAction.js'></script>


<!-- Início do include do captcha para qualquer página -->
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript1.1">

    var popup = true;

    if (window.dialogArguments) { // IE
        window.opener = window.dialogArguments;
    }

    window.onload = load;

    window.onbeforeunload = unload;

    function validaNumeroCaptcha(e){

        var unicode=e.charCode? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
        if (unicode!=8){ //if the key isn't the backspace key (which we should allow)(127=DEL Key)
            if (unicode<48||unicode>57) //if not a number
                return false; //disable key press
        }
        document.getElementById("mensagem").innerHTML = "&nbsp;";

        return true;

    }

    function setTextoCaptchaFocus(){
        document.getElementById('captcha_text').focus();

    }
    function recarregaImagem(){
        document.getElementById('captcha_image').src = "imagens/icon_wait.gif";

        var ran_number = Math.random()*5;
        var captcha_servlet = "captcha.svl?" + ran_number;

        document.getElementById('captcha_image').src = captcha_servlet;
        document.getElementById('captcha_text').value = "";
        document.getElementById('captcha_text').focus();
    }

    function gerar()
    {
        recarregaImagem();
    }


    function load(){                    

        if (window.opener)
        {
            window.opener.document.body.style.opacity = 0.4;
            window.opener.document.body.style.filter = "filter: alpha(opacity=40)";
        }

        setTimeout("gerar()", 1000);              

    }

    function unload()
    {
        if (window.opener)
        {
            window.opener.document.body.style.opacity = 1;
            window.opener.document.body.style.filter = "filter: alpha(opacity=100)";
        }

        var vReturnValue = new Object();
        vReturnValue.captcha_text = document.getElementById("captcha_text").value;
        window.returnValue = vReturnValue;   
    }

    function verificaNumero(campo)
    {
        if (campo.value.length == 5)
        {
            ValidacaoCaptchaAction.isCaptchaValid(campo.value, ret);
        }

    }

    function ret(valido)
    {
        if (valido)
        {

            window.document.getElementById("captcha_text").style.display = "none";            
            window.document.getElementById("wait").innerHTML = "Aguarde...";
            window.document.getElementById("wait").style.display = "inline";            

            if (window.document.getElementById("linkCaptcha"))
            {
                document.location.reload(true);                
            }            

            if (window.opener && popup)
            {            
                window.close();                        
            }
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("mensagem").innerHTML = "O número digitado não corresponde à imagem exibida. Favor informar o código novamente.";
            gerar();
            return false;
        }
    }

</script>

<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <link href="/css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/css/tjmg2007.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <title>Captcha</title>

</head>
<body style="background-color: white;">



    <div id="mensagem" style="color: #FF0000; font-weight: bolder; text-align: center;">&nbsp;</div>


    <table border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td class="medio" align="center" colspan="2">Digite os n&uacute;meros abaixo:</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right" valign="middle" width="60%">

                <img id="captcha_image" src="imagens/icon_wait.gif" onclick="javascript: setTextoCaptchaFocus()" align="middle">

            </td>
            <td width="40%" align="left">
                <input type="text" id="captcha_text" name="captcha_text" value="" size="5" maxlength="5" onkeypress="return validaNumeroCaptcha(event);" onkeyup="return verificaNumero(this);" onkeydown="if (popup && (getBrowser() == 'safari' || getBrowser() == 'opera')) return false;" class="campo_form" autocomplete="off">
                <div id="wait" style="display: none;"/>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="pequeno" align="center" colspan="2">
                <a href="javascript: recarregaImagem()" id="gerar">Gerar nova imagem</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="captchaAudio.svl" onclick="javascript: setTextoCaptchaFocus()">Escutar o c&oacute;digo</a>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="pequeno" align="center" colspan="2">
                <br>Caso a imagem n&atilde;o apare&ccedil;a, clique em 'Gerar nova imagem'.
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>



</body>
```

Quando tem tratamento de formulários basta usar CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, porém neste caso não tem, como proceder?

Comment: Não entendi o que você quer fazer, essa página não submete nem faz a requisição de nenhum dado... é apenas um campo de captcha?

Comment: A página em questão é essa: www4.tjmg.jus.br/juridico/sf/captcha.jsp No caso após digitar o captcha correto a página fica em "loop" eterno, mas permite eu visualizar as páginas de consulta sem que seja necessário digitar outro captcha. Experimente acessar em modo anônimo esse link: http://www4.tjmg.jus.br/juridico/sf/proc_resultado_nome.jsp?nomePessoa=NOME_DA_PESSOA&cpfcnpj=&tipoPessoa=X&naturezaProcesso=1&situacaoParte=A&comrCodigo=NUMERO_DA_COMARCA&numero=1 Vai pedir captcha. Agora acesse o primeiro link dessa resposta, digite o captcha e depois acesse esse segundo, vai acessar normalmente.

Comment: Conseguiu compreender @LuisHenrique ?

Comment: Qual é o cURL que já possui, nada?

Comment: @Inkeliz acompanha aqui os arquivos: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/114152/tjmg-fazer-busca-em-loop-entre-comarcas-com-curl-e-captcha